# Getting time in millis since epoch of event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the time since epoch in milliseconds of an event in javascript - however when I do

`alert('event at exactly' + event.timeStamp);`

It prints numbers in the realm of `8000` to `10000` or a bit more.

Milliseconds since the epoch is usually numbers like `1519211809934`

What am I missing here? How do I properly get the milliseconds since epoch for the exact time an event fired?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `event.timeStamp` measures something [completely different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp):

> This value is the number of milliseconds elapsed from the beginning
> of the current document's lifetime till the event was created.

If you want to get the exact time of when event has been originated, you should add its value to [performance.timeOrigin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timeOrigin) instead. Note that the latter is not supported by Safari.

Alternatively, you can trigger event on your own in the initialization phase of your application, then just compare its timeStamp with `Date.now()`  and use the difference as a document's starting point. That might be useful if there's a significant event loop delay causing the discrepancy between those measurements you worry about.

Note that (judging by the comments) you might still get some fluctuations, as some browsers tend to be less precise with that data:

> To offer protection against timing attacks and fingerprinting, the
> precision of `Event.timeStamp` might get rounded depending on browser
> settings.
>
> In Firefox, the `privacy.reduceTimerPrecision` preference is enabled by
> default and defaults to 20us in Firefox 59; in 60 it will be 2ms. [...]
>
> If you also enable `privacy.resistFingerprinting`, the precision will be 100ms or the value of `privacy.resistFingerprinting.reduceTimerPrecision.microseconds`, whichever is **larger**.

Comment: This would give the exact time in milliseconds of the the time when Date.now() is called. From what I understand, this could be slightly off in milliseconds. I want the EXACT time in milliseconds of the event, to the millisecond, ideally.

Comment: It's an experimental feature of the spec. It's up to the browser if and how to implement it.

Comment: This is an experimental feature so wouldn't be able to be consistently used. Is there any way to get the exact time of the beginning of the current document's lifetime?

Comment: Updated the answer one more time, describing the possible approaches in this case - and the caveat of `resistFingerprinting` techniques.

Comment: As for level of experimentality - well, this API has to replace [PerformanceTiming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming) one - that is considered deprecated, yes still supported by all the browsers (including Safari).